# Compilation failed app:compilieDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been developing one android application with Android studio 2.1.3. Recently I updated my Android Studio to 2.2.3. Now my application giving app:compilieDebugJavaWithJavac error. 
Here is screenshot
[image]
My jdk location
[image]
The only difference i found is In old version i had used default jdk. And now using recommnded one. How to resolve this compiler error.
I tried Clean up, and other stuff. but no use.
Whole log
[image]

My Log OutPut

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library
:app:prepareComMcxiaokeVolleyLibraryAar100Library
:app:prepareComPaypalSdkPaypalAndroidSdk2131Library
:app:prepareIoCardAndroidSdk530Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

\Services\MusicService.java:454: error: cannot find symbol
            musicPlayerNotificationbuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews);
                                          ^
  symbol:   method setCustomBigContentView(RemoteViews)
  location: variable musicPlayerNotificationbuilder of type Builder
\Services\MusicService.java:472: error: cannot find symbol
        musicPlayerNotificationbuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews);
                                      ^
  symbol:   method setCustomBigContentView(RemoteViews)
  location: variable musicPlayerNotificationbuilder of type Builder
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.754 secs
```

build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 17
            versionName "2.0.5"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

            ndk {
                moduleName = "moduleName"
            }
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'
        // CardView
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
        // RecyclerView
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.+'
    }
```

Comment: Can u post whole error log?

Comment: have you `see the compiler error output`?

Comment: Why r u posting only screenshots? can u copy and paste the complete error?

Comment: can u post your build.gradle?

Comment: Error at `MusicService.java:454:` error: cannot find symbol
            `musicPlayerNotificationbuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)`

Comment: that symbol is dot(.)

Comment: @Raghavendra: Any Solution?

Comment: @Moses do u have any jars in your lib folder?

Comment: I don't have jars. But i have .so file.

Comment: In my project i use only one c file. to save some strings.

Comment: @Moses No its different issue its unable to find setCustomBigContentView method of NotificationBuilder

Comment: @Moses yes can u post that implementation? I meant musicPlayerNotificationbuilder. Check the import statement of that NotificationBuilder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129992/discussion-between-moses-and-raghavendra).

Comment: @Raghavendra R u there?

Comment: @Moses Can u post your code how you are implementing the NotificationBuilder?

Comment: i have post my source code. It is in chat room. Click above link.

Comment: @Moses Post how you have solved it.. Might help somebody

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you could try putting the following code in build.gradle under

android {

```
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

So it should look like this:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

At least that works for me, not sure if it will help you. I myself am a starter at this.

Answer (score 0):

Just i have changed everything in my build.gradle file to latest build tools like this. It worked for me

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 17
            versionName "2.0.5"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

            ndk {
                moduleName = "moduleName"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {

        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        //pallette
        compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.1'
        //parse
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
        //appcompat
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
        //design
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
        //volley
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        //paypal
        compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'
        // CardView
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
        // RecyclerView
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    }
```